# Add events in 28-day cycle in FullCalendar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar.js to show tasks entered by users. For this I have created a pop up to take Event basic details and details about recurrence. An event can recur daily, weekly, 28 day, 31 day , 30 day cycles. I have been able to render events for daily and weekly cases but I cant think about how to render events occurrences with 28/30/31 days between them.

My code for calendar is as follows:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //height: 420,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: moment(),
    defaultView: 'month',
    eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
        console.log(event.start.format());
        if (event.ranges == undefined)
            return true;
        else {
            return (event.ranges.filter(function (range) {
                if (range.end == undefined)//Check if only start is given
                    return (event.end.isAfter(range.start))
                else
                    return (event.start.isBefore(range.end) &&//If both start and end date is given
                            event.end.isAfter(range.start));
            }).length) > 0;
        }
    },
    events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
        var events = getEvents(start, end); //This should be a JSON request
        callback(events);
    },
    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
        //$('#btnOpenPopUp').click();
    }
});
```

and json for events is like so:

```
     {
    title: "My repeating event",
    id: 1,
    start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
    end: '14:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
    dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // Repeat monday and thursday
    ranges: [{ 
        start: moment().startOf('month').subtract(1, 'month'), 
        end: moment().startOf('month').subtract(1, 'month').add(7, 'd'),
    }, {
        start: moment('2016-12-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), //all of february
        //end: moment('2016-11-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD').endOf('month'),
    }
```

I need help to render tasks that occur after every 28 days. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could use later.js project (http://bunkat.github.io/later/index.html) to calculate the occurrences of the tasks. This code sample will produce the all occurrences between 2 dates for every 28 days:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="moment-recur-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var recurrence = moment().recur("2016-12-06", "2017-12-06").every(28).days();
var allDates = recurrence.all("L");
console.log(allDates);
</script>
</head>
<body>

test
</body>
</html>
```